# IF statement not working comparing dates

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-calendar-api

The goal is to check google calendar entries (used for scheduling) and place the event title into a spreadsheet. Not everyday has an entry so I used an if statement to leave those cells empty. Everything works except the IF statement. the var 'callday' and 'calendarday' do return a date but when tested against each other it always comes up false. Any ideas? Can I even use dates in the IF statement

```
for (var i = 0; i<10;i++){ 
    var callday = sheet.getSheetValues(i+2,1,1,1)
    var resident = events[x].getTitle()
    var calendarday = events[x].getAllDayStartDate()
     if (callday == calendarday){
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(x);
      x = x+1
     }

}
```

Comment: What did you do to debug this? Did you print out the values you were comparing to see why they are not equal? What are the units of callday and callendarday, do you think: are they dates in days, or are they in milliseconds since 1970, or something else? With these two pieces of information, I bet you could make some progress on your own.

Comment: I printed out the values. In the cells it comes out as 1/1/2016 format. After posting I tried creating two different variables taken from the same piece of information, so callday and callday2 assigning the value in exactly the same way. The IF statement still didn't work. I tried with the other variable and still nothing.